# Creating a variable for each line in a txt file

Tags: python, file, split

I am building a program that will eventually be able to construct finite automata and am in the early stages of reading in the txt file to set up my variables (states, alphabet, starting position, final positions, and rules, respectively). Here is the code I have thus far:

```
def read_dfa(dfa_filename):
    dfa = open(dfa_filename, 'r')
    count = 0
    for line in dfa:
        count += 1
        states, alphabet, initial, final, rules = (line.format(count, line.strip()))
```

The issue I am currently facing is that lines 1:4 will always provide the data I need, however, the **rules** variable could be just line 5, or it could be multiple lines (5:n). How do I make it so I can successfully store the lines I want to each appropriate variable?
This is the error I am faced with: '**ValueError: Too many values to unpack (expected 5)**'
This is an example of what dfa_filename could be:

```
q1,q2   #states
a,b   #alphabet
q1   #initial
q2   #final
q1,a,q2   #rules
q1,b,q1   #rules
q2,a,q2   #rules
q2,b,q2   #rules
```

Comment: I think an easy solution would be to cut off the initial 4 and map/parse those separately and then you could use the entirety of what is left as "rules".

Answer (score 1):

You could use `splitlines` and assign the first 4 lines to `states`, `alphabet`, `initial`,and `final`. Then, assign the remaining lines to `rules`.

```
with open('textfile.txt') as input:
    data = input.read()
    states, alphabet, initial, final = data.splitlines()[0:4]
    rules = data.splitlines()[4:]
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly, the first 4 are always in this order and then there are multiple rules. And the number of rules can change?

If so, try to unpack with `*` Operator. This allows to unpack multiple values into one variable:

```
a, *b = 1, 2, 3
```

results in a=1 and b=[2, 3]

So it should be something around

```
states, alphabet, initial, final, *rules = (line.format(count, line.strip()))
```

Stay save

Answer (score 0):

you can use `list` to unpack file in list and then get needed lines by index numbers.

```
file_lines = list(open('textfile.txt'))
states, alphabet, initial, final = file_lines[0:4]
rules = file_lines[4:]
```